# Join 2 tables by approximate timestamp

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, join

I am using EF, Linq, TSQL. I have two tables:

```
Positions:
Id [int]
Location [geography, nullable]
TimestampLocal [datetimeoffset(7)]
VehicleId [int]

Rawdata:
Id [int]
TimestampLocal [datetimeoffset(7)]
Data1 [string]
VehicleId [int]
```

**I need to join the information from the two tables by timestamp for a specific VehicleId, with timestamps that are close but not identical**. I am using MoreLinq to get that data.
Right now I am taking the positions in a list, then the Rawdata in another list, then iterate over them to get the location of a Rawdata sample, then do something with that information (compute a closestPos.Location.Intersects(Polygon) ...).

```
    var posList = entities.Positions.Where(z => (z.VehicleId == SearchedVehicleId && z.Location != null) 
&& z.TimestampLocal.Day == SearchedDay && z.TimestampLocal.Month == SearchedMonth && z.TimestampLocal.Year == SearchedYear).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(k => k.TimestampLocal);

    var rawdatalist=entities.Rawdata.Where(k => (k.VehicleId == SearchedVehicleId) 
&& k.TimestampLocal.Day == SearchedDay && k.TimestampLocal.Month == SearchedMonth && k.TimestampLocal.Year == SearchedYear).OrderBy(k => k.TimestampLocal).ToList();


    foreach (Rawdata r in rawdatalist){
    var closestPos = posList.MinBy(t => Math.Abs((t.TimestampLocal- r.TimestampLocal).Ticks));
    //do something with the location
    ComputeRawdataforLocation(closestPos, r);
    }
```

Getting the data from the DB (even with AsEnumerable(), ToList()) is fast. The problem is that there are aprox 10k Positions and a 100k of Rawdata values.

How can I speed things up? Another way in Linq? Maybe a TSQL procedure that I can call that would join the values? I have no idea however how to do this in TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting the data from the DB (even with AsEnumerable(), ToList()) is fast.

Ok, then you need to optimize the slow search (`MinBy` is O(N) time complexity).

Forget about LINQ. You can utilize the fact that your `posList` is sorted, which means the linear search can be replaced with much faster O(log(N)) binary search.

The BCL `BinarySearch` methods cannot be used for such scenario. But it's not hard to write the method from scratch, like this:

```
static Positions FindClosest(List<Positions> posList, DateTimeOffset value)
{
    int lo = 0, hi = posList.Count - 1;
    while (lo <= hi)
    {
        int pos = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        var item = posList[pos];
        int compare = value.CompareTo(item.TimestampLocal);
        if (compare < 0) hi = pos - 1;
        else if (compare > 0) lo = pos + 1;
        else return item;
    }
    var next = lo < posList.Count ? posList[lo] : null;
    var prev = lo > 0 ? posList[lo - 1] : null;
    if (next == null) return prev;
    if (prev == null) return next;
    return (value - prev.TimestampLocal).Ticks <= (next.TimestampLocal - value).Ticks ? prev : next;
}
```

and then use it instead of `MinBy`:

```
foreach (Rawdata r in rawdatalist)
{
    var closestPos = FindClosest(posList, r.TimestampLocal);
    //do something with the location
    ComputeRawdataforLocation(closestPos, r);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only had to apply a .ToList() at the end of posList to make it work. This reduced the time on average by 10%. However, I looked in my code and noticed that I had some extra queries that still kept some data on the SQL server (I did not apply an AsEnumerable for them) so I was mixing local IIS data (brought by AsEnumerable) with DB query data (prob. held on the DB server). This left the CPU at 5%. After pulling all the data on the IIS (with AsEnumberable) the CPU went to 40% and computation time decreased dramatically, even more with your code.

Comment: I've missed that `posList` is not a list. But I would suggest you to make sure you call `ToList` at the end of the `var posList = entities....ToList();` and then use it as in the answer (not `ToList` calls inside the inner loop). It should really give much more than 10% - if you have 10K positions, the binary search will use ~13 comparisons while the original will do approx. 5-10K comparisons, so the new method should be times faster.